# puppet agent not recognizing r10k pulled modules

Tags: puppet, r10k

Please help me configuring custom puppet modules from github. The modules are pulled correctly in master but not getting recognized on the agent nodes at all.

**Puppetfile**

```
mod "puppet-lamp",
    :git => "https://github.com/blablabla/puppet_lamp.git",
    :ref => "659fe4056060426d3a1449sdfgbc290571f5714f"
```

**environment.conf**

```
modulepath = modules:$basemodulepath
```

r10k pulls the module from github correctly

```
.
└── production
    ├── environment.conf
    ├── modules
    │   └── lamp
    │       └── manifests
    │           ├── apache.pp
    │           └── test.pp
    └── Puppetfile

4 directories, 4 files
```

**apache.pp**

```
class apache {

  package { 'httpd':
    ensure => installed,
  }

  service { 'httpd':
    enable => true,
    ensure => 'running'
  }

}
```

**site.pp**

```
include apache
```

But when I run the agent, nothing gets applied!

```
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Retrieving locales
Info: Applying configuration version '1549348460'
Notice: Applied catalog in 0.01 seconds
```

Tried using the node definition, no change...

```
node 'default' {
  include 'apache'
}
```

Using latest puppet here

```
[root@puppetmaster environments]# puppetserver --version
puppetserver version: 6.2.0

[root@node01 ~]# puppet -V
6.2.0
```

Could someone please advise on what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class name must match the module name to obey autoloading restrictions. In your case, you have named the module `lamp`, and you have named the class `apache`. The easier route here would be to rename the class `lamp` since it is referenced as `lamp` everywhere else according to your question.

Another autoloading restriction is that your class name must match the module name and manifest name. In this case, your manifest is named `apache.pp`, which means the class would then have to be `lamp::apache` in both definition and declaration. The easier route here would be to rename the manifest from `apache.pp` to `init.pp` so that the class name would just have to match the module name.

Given both of these namespacing problems with your autoloading, the two steps that are easiest to get you working would be:

- Rename definitions and references to `apache` in your manifests to `lamp` (e.g. `class lamp` and `include lamp`).
- Rename your `apache.pp` manifest to `init.pp`.

For further information, you can consult the [Puppet documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.2/lang_namespaces.html) for the version of Puppet that you are using.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining clearly. I understood now. Removed the init.pp, Renamed the apache.pp to init.pp with the class name same as module name. Worked like a charm :-) And the doc link was helpful too.